# Algorithm to Assign Values Based on Constraints

Tags: algorithms, constraint-satisfaction

I have variables x y and z, and I have the values that they can be assigned to, I.E. x can be assigned 1,2, or 3, y can be 1, and z can be 2.  The problem is a constraint that says once a value has been taken by a variable, no other variables can have that value.

The issue that I am running into is if I start with x, how can I efficiently tell that it's value should be 3?

Comment: Is the set of possible values can contain an infinite number of elements?

Comment: Also, how the set of possible values is represented by?

Comment: Set of values is finite, and I am not sure I understand your second question.

Comment: Can we assume that the set of values is represented by a set $S=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n \}$?

Comment: And is there a single constraint as described above, or there are multiple constraints, and one of them is that "once a value has been taken by a variable, no other variables can have that value"?

Comment: I guess I should clarify that the variables x y and z are given a set of values that they are constrained to, I.E if X is given  1, 2, 3 then X can only be 1 ,2 or 3, also the set of values would be positive integer values, Ill just say that at most the values will be between 1 and 7.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are describing amounts to [constraint programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming) and the specific constraint you are talking about is the [alldifferent](http://www.math.unipd.it/~frossi/alldiff.pdf) constraint. I'm not offering a purely algorithmic solution, but reading a bit on constraint programming could give you some ideas on how to construct a search tree where you make a decision (i.e., assign a value to a variable) at each node, and how to backtrack to a feasible node when you reach an infeasible node.